# Multiple mutation: how to have first mutation pass ID to second mutation

Tags: variables, graphql, parameter-passing, react-apollo, graphql-mutation

### Problem

***Problem solved see below***

I would like the ID that is created with the **first mutation** to be used for by the 
**second mutation**. In this the **second mutation** needs the ID from the **first** to work.

example code:

**type Order and Order_rule (back-end)**

```
type Order {
    order_id: ID!
    site_id: ID
    user_id: ID
    customer_name: String
    site: Site! @belongsTo
    order_rules: [Order_rule!]
}

type Order_rule {
    order_rule_id: ID!
    order_id: ID
    photo_id: ID
    product_id: ID
    site_id: ID
    order: Order! @belongsTo
}
```

**CreateOrder and CreateOrder_rule Mutation (back-end)**

```
     createOrder(
     site_id: ID!,
     user_id: ID!,
     customer_name: String!,
     ): Order @field(resolver: "OrderMutator@create")

createOrder_rule(    
    order_id: ID!
    foto_id: ID
    product_id: ID
    site_id: ID
    ): Order_rule @field(resolver: "Order_ruleMutator@create")
```

**Order and OrderRules Mutator are similar (back-end)**

```
    public function create($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context)
    {
        $order = new \App\Order($args);
        $order->save();

        return $order;
    }
```

**react-apollo**

```
mutation createOrderAndOrderRules(
  $site_id: ID!
  $user_id: ID!
  $customer_name: String!
    $order_id: ID!
    $photo_id: ID,
    $product_id: ID,
)
{createOrder(
  site_id: $site_id
  user_id: $user_id
  customer_name: $customer_name
) 
{
order_id
}
 createOrder_rule(
   order_id: $order_id
   photo_id: $photo_id
    product_id: $product_id
    site_id: $site_id
   ) {
    order_id
    photo_id
    product_id
    site_id
     }
}
```

So using the example to explain: I would like the order_id which is an auto-incremented primary key, 
that will be generated from the **createOrder** mutation, to be used for the **createOrder_Rule** 
mutation.

Are there any suggested ways to make this work? I was hoping there is a way to just have multiple 
mutations in one and just pass the information, but I have red in older answers it wasn't possible (yet).
 And I tried to make it work, but couldn't yet find a way to do it.

Any tips to make this work are really appreciated! thanks in advance! :)

### **Problem solved:**

Using input and a mutator in the back-end helps solve the problem. 
Not using the last mutation above anymore. Only using: 
Example code:

**Mutation Order**

```
   createOrder(
    input: OrderInput! @spread
    ): Order @field(resolver: "OrderMutator@create")
```

**Types**

```
type Order {
    order_id: ID!
    site_id: ID
    user_id: ID
    customer_name: String
    site: Site! @belongsTo
    order_rules: [Order_rule!]
}

type Order_rule {
    order_rule_id: ID!
    order_id: ID
    photo_id: ID
    product_id: ID
    site_id: ID
    order: Order! @belongsTo
}
```

**Input types**

```
input OrderInput {
    order_id: ID!
    site_id: ID
    user_id: ID
    customer_name: String
    order_rules: [InputOrder_rule]
}

input InputOrder_rule {
    photo_id: ID
    product_id: ID
    site_id: ID
    order_id: ID
}
```

**Mutator Order *(removed Order_ruleMutator)***

Save Order, Add the Order_rule fields to Order and save Order_rule.

```
use App\Order;
use App\Order_rule;

class OrderMutator
{
    public function create($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context)
    {

        $order = new \App\Order($args);
        $order->save();

        foreach($args['order_rules'] as $orderRules)
        {
            $data_array = 
            array(
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'site_id' => $orderRules['site_id'],
            'photo_id' => $orderRules['photo_id'],
            'product_id' => $orderRules['product_id'],
            );

            $orderRule = new \App\Order_rule($data_array);
            $orderRule->save();            

        }
        return $order;
    }
}
```

This made it work for me, but any additional tips are always welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Problem solved:**

Using input and a mutator in the back-end helps solve the problem.
Not using the last mutation above anymore. Only using:
Example code:

**Mutation Order**

```
   createOrder(
    input: OrderInput! @spread
    ): Order @field(resolver: "OrderMutator@create")
```

**Types**

```
type Order {
    order_id: ID!
    site_id: ID
    user_id: ID
    customer_name: String
    site: Site! @belongsTo
    order_rules: [Order_rule!]
}

type Order_rule {
    order_rule_id: ID!
    order_id: ID
    photo_id: ID
    product_id: ID
    site_id: ID
    order: Order! @belongsTo
}
```

**Input types**

```
input OrderInput {
    order_id: ID!
    site_id: ID
    user_id: ID
    customer_name: String
    order_rules: [InputOrder_rule]
}

input InputOrder_rule {
    photo_id: ID
    product_id: ID
    site_id: ID
    order_id: ID
}
```

**Mutator Order *(removed Order_ruleMutator)***

Save Order, Add the Order_rule fields to Order and save Order_rule.

```
use App\Order;
use App\Order_rule;

class OrderMutator
{
    public function create($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context)
    {
 
        $order = new \App\Order($args);
        $order->save();
    
        foreach($args['order_rules'] as $orderRules)
        {
            $data_array = 
            array(
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'site_id' => $orderRules['site_id'],
            'photo_id' => $orderRules['photo_id'],
            'product_id' => $orderRules['product_id'],
            );

            $orderRule = new \App\Order_rule($data_array);
            $orderRule->save();            

        }
        return $order;
    }
}
```

This made it work for me, but any additional tips are always welcome!